# React.js cannot append child element

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, reactjs

I'm writing a chrome extension for a site built on React.js, where I need to copy an element and append it as the element's sibling. But it doesn't append, not even a plain `<div></div>`. I don't know `react`, so, can you make any parent element with `reactid` not accept more than 'certain' children?
It did append when I tried from `Inspect element -> copy -> paste` in the dev tools, but this might be different.

```
<div data-reactid=".7.0.1.0" class="parent">
    <div data-reactid=".7.0.1.0.0" class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is stateful and renders components with templates. If you manipulate DOM elements controlled by a React component, your manipulations will be erased on the next render.

If a react component is rendering multiple children, the only way to get it to render more children is by updating the component's state. If the underlying application uses a flux architecture, the only way to propagate a change in the state is by calling an action.

[Read more about the flux architecture here](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)